# Does static const member have internal linkage?

Tags: c++, class, static, constants, linkage

Static members of class are compiled as global variable of class scope. How are compiled const static members, and static constexpr members?
Does compiler for every .o file makes copy of this static member or it's done otherwise?

Comment: Regular static const members have external linkage.

Comment: If I put definition of some static const member in class declaration (.h file), why doesn't linker warn me about double definition (if it's external linkage)?

Comment: Because there is a special case for integers. They have no linkage unless you put a definition from them outside the class.

Comment: @NeilKirk they have external linkage in all cases . The special case for integers is only that integers may have an in-class initializer.   The outside definition is required if and only if the variable is *odr-used* .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered by C++14 [class.static.data]/5:

> `Static` data members of a class in namespace scope have external linkage. A local class shall not have static data members.

"A class in namespace scope" means classes that aren't at block scope (aka. "local class").  For example this code:

```
void func()
{
    class C { static const int x = 5; };
}
```

is ill-formed.

---

To answer your question:

> Does compiler for every .o file makes copy of this static member or it's done otherwise?

Typically, if the static member has a definition outside of the class there will be one copy of it, in the object file corresponding to the location of that definition, otherwise there will be none.